# how to convert string to dictionary using python (malformed string)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a = {Po_list:[121,122],product_list:[343,434],site_list:[2,63]}

type(a) is 'str'
```

I tried two things

1. on using ast.literal_eval(a) the output is malformed string
2. on using json.loads(a) or simplejson.loads(a).. output is still

string

How should I do it .. To get the the output as dictionary

Comment: What should come out exactly?

Comment: if `a` is a string on its definition put it in quotes. The same holds for the keys. And move your text outside the code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`literal_eval` works. You somehow fed it the wrong input..

```
a = '{"Po_list": [121, 122], "product_list": [343, 434], "site_list": [2, 63]}'
print(type(a))  # prints: <class 'str'>

from ast import literal_eval as leval

res = leval(a)
print(type(res))  # <class 'dict'>
```

If I missunderstood and the keys are not quoted, you should probably use `regex` to fix that; take a look at the answer by @EricDuminil

Answer (score 3):

If your string looks like `"{Po_list:[121,122],product_list:[343,434],site_list:[2,63]}"`, you only need to convert the keys to strings by adding quotes around them before evaluating `a` :

```
>>> import re
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> a = "{Po_list:[121,122],product_list:[343,434],site_list:[2,63]}"
>>> re.sub('(\w+)(?=:)', '"\g<1>\"', a)
'{"Po_list":[121,122],"product_list":[343,434],"site_list":[2,63]}'
>>> literal_eval(re.sub('(\w+)(?=:)', '"\g<1>\"', a))
{'Po_list': [121, 122], 'product_list': [343, 434], 'site_list': [2, 63]}
```